# How to prevent a record from being affected by the ORDER BY RAND statement in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, php, mysqli

I have a series of problems all which I can't put in the title but I will try to explain them as best as I can. I am building an online exam platform with PHP and MySQL.

Problem 1: Prevent a record from being randomized. 
So I have a series of MCQ questions with each question having 4 options. I have these questions and answers randomized for each student so no two students have the same pattern of questions. I am using the ORDER BY RAND() command to archeive this. My problem now comes for questions like this...Example:
***Question: Which of the following is an input device?
A) Monitor
B) Speaker
C) Printer
D) None of the above.

---

My problem is when the system randomizes these answers the option "D" (None of the above) could change to A or B or C which makes the answer invalid since there are answers below it. So is there a workaround which I can use to prevent randomization for option D only while A, B and C are randomized?

Problem 2: Displaying n questions at a time. 
For MCQ questions where the answers of one question is to be used in the calculation of the next. So let's say I have an MCQ test of questions and question 1 to 5 are related....how can I make the system display these five questions at once instead of 1 question per screen. 
Again how can I let the user be the one to choosr how many questions are displayed at a time...maybe the user wants n questions displayed at the time such that the value of n is the number of questions to be displayed for each screen and a third option where all the questions are displayed at once.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add some flags (or something) to the data.

"None of the above" needs a flag saying it must be last.

Two questions that must be consecutive -- Indicate on the first that a particular question must immediately follow it.

Once you get "business logic" like this, you will probably find that the handling of the flags *and* the randomization may as well be done in client software, not SQL.

A database is a repository for information.  It is not intended as a programming engine.  There are *simple* programming things built into the database (ORDER BY date, ORDER BY rand, filter out stuff; etc), but I suggest that your requirements have crossed the boundary into "gotta do it in a real programming language".

Comment: Okay. Thanks. I understand what you mean.